# In single function how to do two redirect methods in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, controller

In my controller function, I'm trying to do two `redirect()` or `$this->method` activities but this only works for the first one. When the code gets redirect or $this method it will redirect to that function or page. But I need to do two activities side by side like -

> I am using Codeigniter 3.1.10

```
if($result == TRUE) {
$data = array(
details;
);
$this->send_mail($data); //This goes to send_mail functin
$this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Account created successfully.' );
redirect('Dashboard');
}
```

I want something like this. Yes, of course, I have an alternative like - do the further work on my `send_mail()` function but every time I have some other type of messages and body so that's why I want something convenient way to do two work on single time. If anyone gave this kind of idea how to I do this. It's really very great and very easy for me another wise I'll create more than 4 functions for all other tasks.

Comment: In above example, you just wrote 1 redirect.

Comment: Help me understand this: Is there a redirect in the `send_mail()` function? And then you want to redirect to dashboard afterwards? If you make the `send_mail()` function private you could have it return a `boolean` and redirect based on that or you could have it set as `void` and just call it "and forget"

Comment: where does `send_mail()` live? is it a method within the same controller? is it inside a helper? is it on another controller? Calling another method (with `$this->method_name()`) is not a redirect really. What I would suggest is to change the send_mail call to `$somevariable = $this->send_mail($data)`. Doing that, you explicitly force that method to run and assign its output to `$somevariable` instead of actually letting `send_mail` control the flow (it's good practice too, you may need to take different actions depending on what `send_mail()` returns

Comment: Yes, actually $this->send_mail() its method in the same controller, when this line met it I'll go to send_mail() method and rest of line will not execute. That's the problem. But let try your suggestion of $some = $this->send_mail().

Comment: By using $some = $this->send_mail($data); redirect('Dashboar'); In controller when get $some line it goes to send_mail() method without exicuting rest line of code.